# What is the "full name" of the object named "Proc" in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I assume the meaning of the name is a short way to say **proc**edure,

much like of `int` in other OOP languages is shorthand for integer.

I ask this because the Ruby document site didn't addressed it in it's [Proc page](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Proc.html).

Comment: It probably implies procedure, but why does it have to? Why not just let it be what it is?

Comment: This question is more suited for the developers of the Ruby programming language than for Stack Overflow. The developer community at large won't be able to tell you the reason a particular piece of software was designed a certain way.

Comment: It's not about if it has to be or not, but naming classes/objects is essential for language users to understand or get the hint of what the objects does and serves.

Comment: The only person who can answer this question is Yukihiro 'mats' Matsumoto, who to the best of my knowledge does not use [so]. However, I am almost 100% sure that the answer to the question "What is the "full name" of the object named "Proc" in Ruby?" is "Proc."

Comment: @tazmazia : While the inventors of an identifier for sure have something in mind, when they decide to call something _Hash_, or _Module_, or `x`, or, in your case, _Proc_, the details of the name finding process is usually only of interest for people researching the history of programming language, and is usually not documented. Perhaps the IT archaeologists in the far future won't be happy that we didn't document this in our archives, but it's how it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Ruby Language Reference Manual](https://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/Proc.html) (1998 by Yukihiro Matsumoto) refers to it as “procedure object”:

> The `Proc` is the procedure object, which is the encapsulated block with context, such as local variables and stack frames.